# Function pointer with named arguments?

Tags: c, function, pointers

I recently came across a strange syntax in C program.

```
struct connector_agent_api{
    bool (*receive)(slot *s, uint8_t *data, uint8_t length);
}
```

Is "receive" a function pointer?

If it is a function pointer, why does it have named arguments? Should it be like the following one?

```
bool (*receive)(slot *, uint8_t *, uint8_t);
```

It certainly compiled and being used in a library. I searched on internet a lot and tried to justify this kind of syntax. I still don't know why this thing can be compiled... :(

Comment: These names are for self-documentation only, they have no meaning for the functionality.

Comment: Note this is very much like a function declaration in a header file, where parameter names are optional and have no effect on the resulting program.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Same as for any other function declaration that's not a definition.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The names of arguments in a function pointer are optional, just as the names of arguments in a function declaration are optional.  This is because parameter names if given are not used, so both formats are allowed.

In section 6.7.6.3 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding Function Declarators, which includes both function prototypes and function pointers, paragraph 6 states:

> A  parameter  type  list  specifies  the  types  of,  and  may 
>   declare  identifiers  for,  the parameters of the function.

The only place where function parameters require a name is in the actual *definition* of a function.

For a function definition, Section 6.9.1p5 states:

> If  the  declarator  includes  a  parameter  type  list,  the 
>   declaration  of  each  parameter  shall include an identifier, except
>   for the special case of a parameter list consisting of a single
>   parameter of type void , in which case there shall not be an
>   identifier.  No declaration list shall follow.

Answer (score 5):

What makes you think it is a strange syntax? It is a valid declaration as per C standard. The fact that the parameters are named is irrelevant. The naming of such parameters is optional in this case. It can be really helpful if you or someone else is using an IDE because it could display the complete prototype upon using the function pointer to call the function and thus give a hint to the coder about the arguments to be supplied.

Comment: It is also helpful because this sort of struct is used to sort of fake object-like syntax. If the type is actually one meant for the functions to be invoked externally it helps to name the parameters as part of the documentation for that external interface. You are more likely to see code with unnamed parameters to function pointers when the pointers are a callback (rather than call-in).

Comment: @SoronelHaetir Thanks! I like your point on the call-back and call-in.